# Camera app that records EXIF

Tags: applications, camera, photos

Is there a camera app that records EXIF information? In particular, I would need the following:

- GPSLatitude
- GPSLongitude
- GPSImgDirection
- SubjectDistance

I've checked that all these fields can be saved via android. I'm just wondering if there is a camera app that actually DOES save this information in exif for a photo. Most apps I've tried only save max the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Which apps have you tried? That'll help us avoid duplicate suggestions. To start, see Camera FX Pro or GPS Essentials - it has support for Geotagging, although unsure about exact capabilities. By default, the Camera app also can store location data provided you've turned it on in the app options. Which phone / Android version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[Camera360 Ultimate](https://market.android.com/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360) works fine for me. Just, make sure to check "Record GPS Information" from Settings ~> Preferences.

Comment: Camera 360 doesn't seem to record GPSImgDirection. I'm still looking for a program that does, though there are several that claim to ... and don't.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer here is that the GPS system only provides direction if the receiver is moving.

Comment: GPS doesn't provide any direction. It only provides coordinates for an object sought by the user. When an object moves, its coordinates changes, thus, it appears that GPS is tracking the movement, but it is only providing the coordinates, that is all. The  tracking is shown in the application. The coordinates can be used in the EXIF information.